# How to loop through string[] in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

In this postgressql function i created a array by spliting a string. Now i want loop on this array and do some processing on it.

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getAllFoo() RETURNS character varying as
$BODY$
DECLARE
   arr_split_data text[];
   counter character varying;
begin

    counter := ''; -- Init value

    -- split data. Add in array
    select into arr_split_data regexp_split_to_array('a,b,c,d,e,f',',');

    FOR r IN arr_split_data -- error
    LOOP
         counter := arr_split_data[r] || '_' || counter; -- do some processing
    END LOOP;

  return counter;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

But I am getting this error

[image: error]

when I execute this function. Is my syntax for loop is wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getAllFoo() RETURNS character varying as
    $BODY$
    DECLARE
        r               character varying;    
        arr_split_data  text[];
        counter         character varying;
    begin
        counter := ''; -- Init value

        -- split data. Add in array
        select into arr_split_data regexp_split_to_array('a,b,c,d,e,f',',');

        FOREACH r IN array arr_split_data LOOP
            counter := counter || '_' || r; -- do some processing
        END LOOP;
        return counter;

    END
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Answer (score 10):

The syntax is

```
FOREACH r IN ARRAY arr_split_data
LOOP
  counter := r || '_' || counter;
  -- do some processing
END LOOP;
```

You'll need to declare `r` too:

```
DECLARE
    arr_split_data TEXT [];
    r              CHARACTER VARYING;
    counter        CHARACTER VARYING;
BEGIN
```

See section 41.6.5 of the manual: [Looping Through Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY)

Comment: not working. Error - **loop variable of FOREACH must be a known variable or list of variables**

Comment: @Deepakgupta: then declare the variable `r`